# How do I set permission to checkin to a branch in Azure Devops using TFVC

Tags: azure-devops

How do I set permission to checkin to a branch with approval flow in Azure Devops using TFVC.

Comment: What do you mean "with approval flow"?

Comment: yes with approval flow before merging into a branch

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't. TFVC has no equivalent to Git branch policies.

Answer (score 0):

Like Daniel wrote, in TFVC you don't have branch policies and pull request like Git.

The closest thing to that is Code Review and Check In policy:

You need to install in each developer pc the [Colin's ALM Checkin Policies](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2017) (is Visual Studio extension), then to apply the Code Review Policy, this policy allows you to enforce [Code Review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops) at check in time.

In the code review, you can accept/decline the developer change and is kind of "approval flow".

The code review policy:

[image]